# Android dynamic list dialog

Tags: java, android, list, dynamic, dialog

Hi i'm looking to create a list dialog that gets the items on the list from a directory I can set up a list dialog like this

```
final CharSequence[] items = {<dynamic list of folder contents here>};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Pick a File");
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}).show();
```

Now lets say the directory i want to get the items from is /sdcard/folder
and it contains some files

```
sample.txt 
sample.zip
file1.txt
file1.zip
```

The list dialog that would appear would have the options

```
sample.txt
sample.zip
file1.txt
file1.zip
```

and one is pressed it can just toast the name of the file selected thanks for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never you will do something like this

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Agenda/files");       
final String[] items = dir.list();
```

then pass items to the dialog as you have showed.